# Search within Matrix field doesn't work

Tags: search

recently I've found out that my search is not showing all the entries that it should. I'm on the Craft 3.9.10

1. I have a Matrix field with *Use this field’s values as search keywords* checkbox **checked** for both the Matrix and the Redactor field.
2. I have the "String" filled in this Matrix -> Redactor field for the entry I'm searching
3. I saved the entry
4. I ran `php craft resave/entries --update-search-index` to re-save and re-index the search index
5. I'm using this code to search the entries `results = craft.entries.search(query).orderBy('score').all()`
6. When I search for the "String", the entry is not in the list of entries.

Could you help me please?